# Project setup: Having one web project depend on another

Tags: eclipse

I would like to have two "Dynamic Web Projects" in Eclipse. One basically "extends" the other so I would like to define the second as having access to the code and the JARs of the first.

Is this possible in Eclipse? If so, how?

In the "Java Build path" of the second project, in the "Projects" tab I have included the first project. In the "Java Build path" of the first project, in the "Order and Export" I have marked that its JARs etc should be exported. Compilation works fine.

When I deploy the second project, it cannot find any of the JARs or the code of the first project. If I go to "Deployment Assembly" of the second project and add the first project, it inserts "WEB-INF/lib/first.war" into the deployment assembly; this isn't very helpful, a WAR doesn't belong there. I see no other way to add compiled code and JARs from the first project into the deployment of the second.

What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is to open the plugin.xml of the project you want to add the dependency to. On the dependencies tab you can add the project you it needs to depends on. I think this will keep you going.

Regads